# (onSelectionChange) call a function and send the value [Angular Material] (undefiend)

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I would love for your help.
I try to get the value of selected item and send the value to function.

component html:

```
<mat-form-field style="text-align: right">
    <input type="text" placeholder="type..." matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="selected($event)" *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.companyName">
              {{option.companyName}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

component ts:

```
  // Selected option function triger
  selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

the event call the function but is console undefiend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `optionSelected` on the `mat-autocomplete` element.

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)='selected($event.option.value)'>


// Selected option function triger
selected(value: string) {
   console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: try `onSelectionChanged` instead of `optionSelected` on `<mat-autocomplete`

Comment: try addding ngModel value to autocomplete